# Using L9110 (or HG7881) with external power supply

Tags: arduino, voltage, dc-motor

I want to drive a DC motor with a L9110 H bridge IC using an Arduino UNO with an external 12V power supply like [this](http://diyprojects.eu/how-to-use-h-bridge-hg7881-with-external-power-supply-and-arduino/)

The breadboard for the L9110 he is using is the following :

[image]

[image: Schematic]

If VCC is 12V and IB and IA of the L9110 are conected to 12V and the connected to the 5V pins of the Arduino ... why the Arduino is not getting fried? I Guess the resistor has something to do with it but what is the reason for that? is there a better design?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP could quite easily find out by raising a comment on the site he has linked. And of course the answer to your question: "is there a better design?" is of course.

Comment: I don't see why this question is better answered on the site linked, the breadboard is a generic board anyone can buy and this site is to share knowledge

Comment: Firstly, it's not a breadboard, it's a PCB. Secondly, you have shown no effort in trying to resolve this yourself - you could have looked around for the driver IC on the board and linked to its data sheet. You could have found a pdf explaining how it should be used (I see one on the web) and you could have checked to see if the pull-ups would cause problems with the arduino outputs by reading relevant arduino documents.

Comment: Sorry for not being as expert as you are, in any case your scolding does not answer my question to why this question is better asked on the linked website and not on stackexchange.

Comment: Your adruino is also "connected" to mains voltage (unless you run it on batteries), so why would 12V be a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why the Arduino is not getting fried? I Guess the resistor has something to do with it but what is the reason for that?

The answer is that the [L9110](https://www.elecrow.com/download/datasheet-l9110.pdf) is *designed* for this purpose. The OA and OB pins are *inputs* and don't pass the 12 V supply back to the micro-controller. The datasheet states the inputs are

> TTL / CMOS output level compatible, and can be
>   directly connected to the CPU;

The second table on the datasheet shows:

```
Test conditions： Vcc =9V , Iout =750mA
Symbol Parameters     minimum      Typical     maximum     units
VHin Input high       2.5          5.0         9.0         V
VLin Input low        0            0.5         0.7         V
```

The micro-controller output just has to be < 0.5 V when low and > 2.5 V when high to guarantee correct operation.

The resistors don't have anything to do with the logic control signal from the micro. They are there to provide a weak pull-up on the signals out to the next stage - typically the stepper driver amplifier.

> Is there a better design?

This one is fine. It should do what it says.